# Copy field value from a point feature class to another field in a line feature class

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, geometric-network

I have a point feature  and a line feature in a geometric network. I am trying to find a way ( Tool or script) to copy values from a field in the point feature and paste them in the line feature. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Attribute Transfer Tool that is on the Spatial Adjustment Toolbar. You can define source and target feature classes along with a Field matching dialog. You must manually select a feature in the Source layer and then select a feature in the Target layer.